# One particular user has a 403 Forbidden when communicating with our auth servers

Tags: c#, http-headers, http-status-codes

One specific user has been encountering an issue communicating with our authentication server. So I decided I would request some diagnostic information from him, mainly through sending us the `status code` he receives when he is talking to our auth server (that particular address is https://xxxxxxxx.com/server/authentication.php).

The header request code contains a cookie container to store information about this session and does ***not*** allow redirects (this is on purpose):

```
List<string> headers = new List<string>();
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
webRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
{
    headers.Add("Status Code: " + (int)webResponse.StatusCode);
    headers.Add("Status Desc: " + webResponse.StatusDescription);
    foreach (string key in webResponse.Headers.Keys)
    {
        if (!key.ToString().Equals("Location"))
        {
            var value = webResponse.Headers[key];
            headers.Add(key + ": " + value);
        }
    }
}
```

The desired output should be a `302 Found` as we redirect those trying to access anything but `xxxxxxxx.com` back to the main domain.

This is the output the user receives:

[image]

According to status code documentation, `<403> Forbidden` means:

`The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity. If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 404 (Not Found) can be used instead.`

Since this is the only user that's had this issue, we know that it's not our servers that's the issue, and likely has to do with the firewall configurations this particular issue has within their servers.

I was wondering what I could do at this point to help this user ameliorate this `403` error?

Comment: I would ask him to run a Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) session while using your app, and then send you the results.

Comment: From experience Fiddler took a bit too much configuring for my comfort to ask a user to use. The HTTPS certificate part (which requires accepting the dialog) makes me uncomfortable to let a user use. Are there any other ways?